# py2exe python24 numpy error AttributeError "dtype"

Tags: python, numpy, py2exe

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

from distutils.filelist import findall
import os
import matplotlib
matplotlibdatadir = matplotlib.get_data_path()
matplotlibdata = findall(matplotlibdatadir)
matplotlibdata_files = []
for f in matplotlibdata:
    dirname = os.path.join('matplotlibdata', f[len(matplotlibdatadir)+1:])
    matplotlibdata_files.append((os.path.split(dirname)[0], [f]))


packages = ['matplotlib', 'pytz']
includes = []
excludes = []
dll_excludes = ['libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll',
                'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
                'libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                'wxmsw26uh_vc.dll']


opts = { 'py2exe': { 'packages' : packages,
                     'includes' : includes,
                     'excludes' : excludes,
                     'dll_excludes' : dll_excludes
                    }
         }

setup ( console=['test.py'],
        options = opts,
        data_files = matplotlibdata_files
        )
```

I compile the application by running `>setup.py py2exe`

At the end of compilation phase, it is written :

```
The following modules appear to be missing

['AppKit', 'FFT', 'Foundation', 'Image', 'LinearAlgebra', 'MA', 'MLab', 'Matrix', 'Numeric', 'PyObjCTools', 'P
yQt4', 'Pyrex', 'Pyrex.Compiler', 'RandomArray', '_curses', '_ssl', 'backends.draw_if_interactive', 'backends.
new_figure_manager', 'backends.pylab_setup', 'backends.show', 'cairo', 'cairo.gtk', 'fcompiler.FCompiler', 'fc
ompiler.show_fcompilers', 'fltk', 'gd', 'gobject', 'gtk', 'lib.add_newdoc', 'matplotlib.enthought.pyface.actio
n', 'mlab.amax', 'mlab.amin', 'numarray', 'numarray.convolve', 'numarray.fft', 'numarray.ieeespecial', 'numarr
ay.linear_algebra', 'numarray.linear_algebra.mlab', 'numarray.ma', 'numarray.numeric', 'numarray.random_array'
, 'numerix.ArrayType', 'numerix.Complex', 'numerix.Complex32', 'numerix.Complex64', 'numerix.Float', 'numerix.
Float32', 'numerix.Float64', 'numerix.Int', 'numerix.Int16', 'numerix.Int32', 'numerix.Int8', 'numerix.NewAxis
', 'numerix.UInt16', 'numerix.UInt32', 'numerix.UInt8', 'numerix.absolute', 'numerix.add', 'numerix.all', 'num
erix.allclose', 'numerix.alltrue', 'numerix.arange', 'numerix.arccos', 'numerix.arccosh', 'numerix.arcsin', 'n
umerix.arcsinh', 'numerix.arctan', 'numerix.arctan2', 'numerix.arctanh', 'numerix.argmax', 'numerix.argmin', '
numerix.argsort', 'numerix.around', 'numerix.array', 'numerix.arrayrange', 'numerix.asarray', 'numerix.asum',
'numerix.bitwise_and', 'numerix.bitwise_or', 'numerix.bitwise_xor', 'numerix.ceil', 'numerix.choose', 'numerix
.clip', 'numerix.compress', 'numerix.concatenate', 'numerix.conjugate', 'numerix.convolve', 'numerix.cos', 'nu
merix.cosh', 'numerix.cross_correlate', 'numerix.cumproduct', 'numerix.cumsum', 'numerix.diagonal', 'numerix.d
ivide', 'numerix.dot', 'numerix.equal', 'numerix.exp', 'numerix.fabs', 'numerix.fft.fft', 'numerix.fft.inverse
_fft', 'numerix.floor', 'numerix.fmod', 'numerix.fromfunction', 'numerix.fromstring', 'numerix.greater', 'nume
rix.greater_equal', 'numerix.hypot', 'numerix.identity', 'numerix.indices', 'numerix.innerproduct', 'numerix.i
scontiguous', 'numerix.less', 'numerix.less_equal', 'numerix.log', 'numerix.log10', 'numerix.logical_and', 'nu
merix.logical_not', 'numerix.logical_or', 'numerix.logical_xor', 'numerix.matrixmultiply', 'numerix.maximum',
'numerix.minimum', 'numerix.mlab.amax', 'numerix.mlab.amin', 'numerix.mlab.cov', 'numerix.mlab.diff', 'numerix
.mlab.hanning', 'numerix.mlab.rand', 'numerix.mlab.std', 'numerix.mlab.svd', 'numerix.multiply', 'numerix.nega
tive', 'numerix.newaxis', 'numerix.nonzero', 'numerix.not_equal', 'numerix.nx', 'numerix.ones', 'numerix.outer
product', 'numerix.pi', 'numerix.power', 'numerix.product', 'numerix.put', 'numerix.putmask', 'numerix.rank',
'numerix.ravel', 'numerix.repeat', 'numerix.reshape', 'numerix.resize', 'numerix.searchsorted', 'numerix.shape
', 'numerix.sin', 'numerix.sinh', 'numerix.size', 'numerix.sometrue', 'numerix.sort', 'numerix.sqrt', 'numerix
.subtract', 'numerix.swapaxes', 'numerix.take', 'numerix.tan', 'numerix.tanh', 'numerix.trace', 'numerix.trans
pose', 'numerix.typecode', 'numerix.typecodes', 'numerix.where', 'numerix.which', 'numerix.zeros', 'numpy.Comp
lex', 'numpy.Complex32', 'numpy.Complex64', 'numpy.Float', 'numpy.Float32', 'numpy.Float64', 'numpy.Infinity',
 'numpy.Int', 'numpy.Int16', 'numpy.Int32', 'numpy.Int8', 'numpy.UInt16', 'numpy.UInt32', 'numpy.UInt8', 'nump
y.inf', 'numpy.infty', 'numpy.oldnumeric', 'objc', 'paint', 'pango', 'pre', 'pyemf', 'qt', 'setuptools', 'setu
ptools.command', 'setuptools.command.egg_info', 'trait_sheet', 'matplotlib.numerix.Float', 'matplotlib.numerix
.Float32', 'matplotlib.numerix.absolute', 'matplotlib.numerix.alltrue', 'matplotlib.numerix.asarray', 'matplot
lib.numerix.ceil', 'matplotlib.numerix.equal', 'matplotlib.numerix.fromstring', 'matplotlib.numerix.indices',
'matplotlib.numerix.put', 'matplotlib.numerix.ravel', 'matplotlib.numerix.sqrt', 'matplotlib.numerix.take', 'm
atplotlib.numerix.transpose', 'matplotlib.numerix.where', 'numpy.core.conjugate', 'numpy.core.equal', 'numpy.c
ore.less', 'numpy.core.less_equal', 'numpy.dft.old', 'numpy.random.rand', 'numpy.random.randn']
```

1) First Problem: `numpy\core\_internal.pyc not included in Library.zip`

```
No scipy-style subpackage 'core' found in C:\WinCE\Traces\py2exe test\dist\library.zip\numpy. Ignoring: No module named _internal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "profiler_ftt.py", line 15, in ?
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import Toolbar, FigureCanvasWx,\
  File "matplotlib\backends\backend_wx.pyc", line 152, in ?
  File "matplotlib\backend_bases.pyc", line 10, in ?
  File "matplotlib\colors.pyc", line 33, in ?
  File "matplotlib\numerix\__init__.pyc", line 67, in ?
  File "numpy\__init__.pyc", line 35, in ?
  File "numpy\_import_tools.pyc", line 173, in __call__
  File "numpy\_import_tools.pyc", line 68, in _init_info_modules
  File "<string>", line 1, in ?
  File "numpy\lib\__init__.pyc", line 5, in ?
  File "numpy\lib\type_check.pyc", line 8, in ?
  File "numpy\core\__init__.pyc", line 6, in ?
  File "numpy\core\umath.pyc", line 12, in ?
  File "numpy\core\umath.pyc", line 10, in __load
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_ARRAY_API'
```

I resolved that issue by adding the file `...\Python24\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_internal.pyc` in `...\test\dist\library.zip\numpy\core`.
Each time I compile that executable, I add the file by hand.
Does anybody know how to automatically add that file?

2) Second problem: I don't know how to resolve that issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "profiler_ftt.py", line 15, in ?
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import Toolbar, FigureCanvasWx,\
  File "matplotlib\backends\backend_wx.pyc", line 152, in ?
  File "matplotlib\backend_bases.pyc", line 10, in ?
  File "matplotlib\colors.pyc", line 33, in ?
  File "matplotlib\numerix\__init__.pyc", line 67, in ?
  File "numpy\__init__.pyc", line 35, in ?
  File "numpy\_import_tools.pyc", line 173, in __call__
  File "numpy\_import_tools.pyc", line 68, in _init_info_modules
  File "<string>", line 1, in ?
  File "numpy\random\__init__.pyc", line 3, in ?
  File "numpy\random\mtrand.pyc", line 12, in ?
  File "numpy\random\mtrand.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "numpy.pxi", line 32, in mtrand
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I don't find the file `numpy.pxi` in my file tree nor in `\test\dist\library.zip`.
I browsed the web in the hope to find a solution but nothing.
It seems that this issue is well known but no solution provided in mailing lists.