# AttributeError in Py2exe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, py2exe, attributeerror

I made my `py` file executable using `py2exe`. My `setup.py` is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=['main.py'])
```

When I tried to run `main.exe`, I get an error and was referred to `main.log` which reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<loader>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<loader>", line 6, in __load
  File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 2839, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:79846)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<loader>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<loader>", line 6, in __load
  File "pandas\algos.pyx", line 64, in init pandas.algos (pandas\algos.c:179610)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<loader>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<loader>", line 6, in __load
  File "pandas\lib.pyx", line 1, in init pandas.lib (pandas\lib.c:77889)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__pyx_capi__'
```

It looks like line 20 in my `main.py` file (`import pandas as pd`) triggered the problem. This type of error is referenced in a pull request [here](https://bitbucket.org/khinsen/mmtk/pull-request/6/add-__init__-file-for-cython/diff#chg-Src/MMTK/__init__.py) and they suggested adding a blank `__init__.py` file. I did so and got same result. I found a well commented post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute) (not directly dealing with py2exe) that suggests this might be due to mutual top-level imports or circular dependencies. This problem seems well known and has been mentioned at least twice on Stackoverflow in the past year (e.gs: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752652/py2exe-python24-numpy-error-attributeerror-dtype) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973913/how-can-i-import-python-libraries-with-pyx-and-c-files-without-installing-on-t)) but no clear solution has been given.

Perhaps we can get more clarity now with your feedback.

**Python 3.4.2; py2exe 0.9.2.0**

Answer (score 0):

Was running into the same issue with pandas, but I got it working after updating to the most recent version.

It seems this error was recently addressed, and was resolved in Pandas 15.2
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8602

Answer (score 0):

I was running in the same errors with Python 3.4.4.

My solution was to fix the import statement in C:\Pythob34\lib\site-packagespythoncom.py.

Original:
import pywintypes
pywintypes.**import_pywin32_system_module**("pythoncom", globals())

Changed To:
from pywintypes import **import_pywin32_system_module**
**import_pywin32_system_module**("pythoncom", globals())